# How to show the location of a conference in BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a bibliography of sources in computer science, many of which are conference papers.  For these, I use the `inproceedings` entry type.  This includes an "optional" or "nonstandard" `location` field, which is where I and my lab colleagues have always stored the location where the conference had taken place.  However, none of the styles I have tried to use so far display the `location` field.  So I have two questions:

1. What styles show the `location` field, at least for an `inproceedings` entry?
2. How does one normally or usually show the location of a conference, if the `location` field doesn't work with the usual styles (e.g., `plain`, `ams`, `ieeetr`, `amsplain`)?  Do you use the `address` field?

Comment: Have you found yet a good answer? I think you can approve Boris' answer because it is sufficient here.

Answer (score 17):

1. The styles `aomalpha.bst` and `aomplain.bst` that I've updated and currently support for *The Annals of Mathematics* have `VENUE` field for conference proceedings.
2. If the bib style does not have `VENUE`, I usually put the location in the `ADDRESS` field - there is a certain abuse of the field since it is supposed to be the publisher's address, but this probably can be forgiven.  For example,

   ```
   @Proceedings{ION-GPS-94,
      title =        {ION GPS-94 Proceedings},
      year =         1994,
      booktitle =    {ION GPS-94 Proceedings},
      number =       7,
      series =       {International Technical Meeting of
                 The Satellite Division of The Institute of Navigation},
      month =        {September},
      address =      {Salt Palace Convention Center, Salt Lake City, UT},
      organization = {Institute of Navigation}
   }
   ```

   Of course, `VENUE` field is better :)

Comment: How would you go about filling in the location, if the publisher, publisher address and the conference location should be filled in?

Comment: You can put conference location into the conference title then

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing, because I noticed that if you use both `@address` and `@location`, `@address` is ignored and `@location` is used as the address of the publisher. Sad.

Answer (score 0):

The ACM's 'acmart' package's BST file does handle location for BibTeX types `@inproceedings` and `@proceedings`. The `location` field is used for the venue. In ACM data `location` value is usually in the form "city, country", i.e. "Rome, Italy" or with the state's abbreviation for US venues "New York, NY, USA".

If `location` is not supplied but `city` is and has a value, the `city` data is used instead.

See `FUNCTION { format.city }` in lines 1291–1326 of file 'ACM-Reference-Format.bst' in the 'acmart' package.

Part of the problem here is different publishers use the same BibTeX fields differently so to truly conform to a particular publishers format you may need to edit output from reference managers (or define per-publisher export formats). For those who keep static BibTeX files (i.e. 'manual' resources) one could keep a version per publisher—or at least for those to which you submit often.

Also, don't rely on a publishers digital library's citation info in BibTeX from. I'd guess it's done by a different team to those who maintain the format. Far from ideal, but it helps explain why it is hard, even for the well-intentioned, to easily format references consistently.